# Laravel 5 Session not persisting reliably

Tags: php, laravel, session, transactions

I love this site, able to find answers to all my questions until now.

I have a two Ajax transaction process here, where in the first transaction the values entered are put into the Session, the second transaction retrieves values entered and the previous transactions values in order to know how to proceed. This statement does not appear to be reliable, but it works better than 90% of the time. Why is it not reliable? The transaction completes successfully, and the screen appears correctly formatted.

```
Session::put('previous', serialize($entry));
```

Example transaction A;
User scans an item UPC, the transaction identifies the UPC 0587 as correct, creates $entry, and responds back to the user "Please put 0587 into tote 3334"

```
$entry = (object) ['type' => 'UPC', 'text' => '0587'];
Session::put('previous', serialize($entry));
```

Example transaction B;
Users scans the tote, the transaction identifies tote 3334 as correct, then asks for the previous transaction entry

```
$previous = (object) unserialize(Session::get('previous', self::UNKNOWN_SERIAL));
```

Better than 90% of the time $previous equals what we want (UPC, 0587). Sometimes $previous equals the values from a prior transaction before transaction A. $previous would equal self::UNKNOWN_SERIAL on the first transaction after logon.

Why does Session::put(..) appear unreliable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some details about A) your server infrastructure, and B) which session driver you're using?

Comment: Yes, the example above happened on my development site, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu). As for Session driver, in .env SESSION_DRIVER=file, in config/session.php 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'), 'lifetime' => 120, 'expire_on_close' => true, 'encrypt' => false,

Comment: Yes, in my dev environment, a single server.

Comment: In production, multiple servers, we have .env SESSION_DRIVER=database to enable the same session data across servers

Comment: I'd think you would want to use the same driver in both envs, that way you're only debugging problems that will affect production. This issue may even go away if you switch to DB sessions in dev.

Comment: This issue is also happening in production, that's why I'm looking into it.

Comment: How did you generate your database sessions table? Did you use the `php artisan session:table` command?

Comment: Yes, php artisan session:table, composer dump-autoload, php artisan migrate:status and php artisan migrate. Remember, it works perfectly better than 90% of the time, using SESSION_DRIVER=database or SESSION_DRIVER=file.

Comment: Took mopo922's suggestion and changed my development site to SESSION_DRIVER=database. Increased logging and recreated the issue twice yesterday. There may be an issue with multiple instream transactions, not sure yet, but this may be a serialization issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out is was a serialization issue. Changed the storage of $entry between these two transactions using Request::session()->getId(); as part of the key. This has resolved the issue. Testing showed that other instream transactions using the same Request::session() caused this issue.